# MediaWiki CSS not loading, MIME type error

Tags: php, css, mediawiki

My MediaWiki install on Gandi.net is having CSS problems: The [main page](http://jollof.mariadavydenko.com/wiki/index.php) works fine. However, all of the [other pages](http://jollof.mariadavydenko.com/wiki/index.php?title=Special:RecentChanges) are unstyled, as though the browser can't access the CSS.

I've tried using the console to debug in Chrome and get the following error message:

`Refused to apply style from 'http://jollof.mariadavydenko.com/wiki/load.php?debug=false&lang=en&modules=mediawiki.feedlink%2Chelplink%2CsectionAnchor%7Cmediawiki.legacy.commonPrint%2Cshared%7Cmediawiki.skinning.content.externallinks%7Cmediawiki.skinning.interface%7Cmediawiki.special.changeslist%7Cmediawiki.special.changeslist.enhanced%2Clegend%7Cskins.monobook.styles&only=styles&skin=monobook' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`

I am running PHP version 5.6 and MySQL version 5.7. I've tried the `load.php` [.htaccess fix](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Load.php) recommended for these symptoms but it doesn't work -- load.php loads just fine. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: text/html needs to be text/css

Comment: If you actually access that page, you'll see why its giving you the error, it's a php error page. specifically this error `require_once(/srv/data/web/vhosts/jollof.mariadavydenko.com/htdocs/wiki/vendor/oyejorge/less.php/lib/Less/Cache.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/data/web/vhosts/jollof.mariadavydenko.com/htdocs/wiki/vendor/oyejorge/less.php/lib/Less/Parser.php on line 3` looks like it can't find a library in the vendor folder, did you run composer install?

Comment: I did, but it looks like it was interrupted. I reuploaded the missing `Cache.php` file and others and everything seems to work now. Phew!

Answer (score 1):

The `Cache.php` file was missing due to an incomplete install. All fixed.